# How can I prove that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \sum_{(d|n)} \frac{1}{d}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, divisor-sum

I want to show that $\displaystyle \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \sum_{(d|n)}  \frac{1}{d}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$.

This is essentially a basic number theory question.
I am able to get to the point where I get
$$
\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}= \frac{\sum_{(d|n)} d}{n}
$$ but I don't know if I can do anything further.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please consider adding Mathjax. There are many tutorials all over the internet.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{d \mid n} \frac{n}{d} = \sum_{d \mid n} d$

Comment: To prove the hint, show that $f(d)=n/d$ is a bijection from the set of divisors of $n$ to itself.

Answer (score 8):

$$n \sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d}=\sum_{d|n} \frac{n}{d}=\sum_{d|n} {d} = \sigma(n) $$

Have you understood it?
I have used the equality: $\sum\limits_{d|n} {f(d)}=\sum\limits_{d|n} {f(\frac{n}{d})}$.

Comment: you can use `\sum` for summations (then they will format like sums, rather than like the greek letter `\Sigma`, which will format like a normal symbol).

Comment: To the OP: if you do not see why evinda’s answer works, try it for small $n$. Once you see why it is so, you will say ‘oh!’ And slap your forehead.